# Why does calling setLayoutParams on subview trigger layout on parent view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom view with a TextView inside it. When I update the layoutParams of the TextView, a requestLayout is trigger on the parent view. Does anybody know why? Is there any way to position the TextView inside its parent without having to re-layout the entire parent view?

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)childTextView.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0, 100, 0, 0);
childTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The `setLayoutParams` call above is what triggers the layout pass that I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--- *??*

**NO!!**

*do you know what `LayoutParams` does* ? It does what it does, and its function is the what you are seeing.

Parents best care for their children based on what they have, derived from their children - `LayoutParams` tells a parent how a child is suppose to be treated. if that changes the Parent needs to re-adjust his care towards that child.

So *NO* there is no way -(*you have to live with that.*)

Comment: but why does the PARENT VIEW have to re-layout? why not just the child view? "do you know what `LayoutParams` does?" -- you never really told me what it actually does. You just said "It does what it does"...

Comment: because the parent is dirty now - suppose the parent has a width of `WRAP_CONTENT` and you adjust the width of your child to 500, should the parent re-adjust itself? or not? if not, there will be a problem on your parent view right?, requestlayout() runs  a top to down layout pass ..@dmoss18

Comment: Makes sense, but suppose your parent has a hard-coded width and height, and the child view just sets its margins, like what I have above. Doesn't seem like the parent should be dirty.